# Проблема при получние данных в запросе

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Когда я совершаю запрос на удаление предмета, при получении ответа я посылаю следующий запрос на обновление списка.
Но *через раз* бывает, что при получение данных, там находится предмет,который я ранее удалил.
Возникает вопрос, это происходит вследствии того, что сервер плохо работает ? Или же я делаю запрос слишком рано ?
Хотя я вроде бы делаю запрос после завершения предыдущего (await). Можно ли в таком случае использовать задержку setTimeout, и не является ли это костылём ?

```
category === 'rated' ?
await profileAPI.deleteRateItems(movie_id,type,session)
:
await profileAPI.deleteFavoriteItem(id,type,session,movie_id);
setTimeout(()=>{
    dispatch(getProfileItems(type,id,session,category));
},300)
```

Comment: А точно удаление происходит? проверяйте, что вам приходит в ответ от сервера

Comment: Да, сервер возвращяет сообщение об успешном удалении